# Which carriers offer cheap one-ways from Europe to the United States

Tags: air-travel, usa, budget, europe, one-way

Airlines seem to charge almost as much for a one-way from Europe to the US as for a round-trip, at least in the next couple months when I'm planning to fly.

I discovered Condor Air was a big exception to this, offering one-way Frankfurt -> US flights for much less than a round-trip. This made me hope there were other similar "discount carriers" doing the EU->US trip. I'd prefer to find a carrier flying out of London, Spain or Italy.

Anyone know of other "discount carriers" that fly EU -> US? Or are there other options to get a more "reasonable" one-way ticket?

Comment: Pakistan airlines.  Barcelona to Chicago for 300 euro.

Comment: Norwegian do, too.

Answer (score 5):

[Air Transat](http://www.airtransat.co.uk/en/index.aspx) offers flights to Canada (Paris-Montreal can be quite cheap out of summer, even few days before booking).

[Icelandair](http://www.icelandair.co.uk) to North America via Reykjavik (they even offer the possibility for a stopover in Iceland if you want to visit). Icelandair have specific "gateways" on each side of the Ocean, airports for which they have more frequent and cheaper flights.

Both airlines have reasonable prices for their One-Way flights (still not much less than 400 euros)

I also once flew over the ocean booking via [Hipmunk](http://www.hipmunk.com/flights/LON-to-NYC#!dates=Apr20p2&pax=1) and the deal was great, but I don't know how often that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is to broad (where in USA? where in Europe? When?) but if you don't put any restrictions (anywhere in EU, anywhere in USA, in the next two month) these are some results:

- AGP-LAX 14th May: **218 €** with Norwegian
- MAD-LAX 13th May: **210 €** with Norwegian
- BGO-JFK 16th May: **136 €** with Norwegian

It makes clear that [Norwegian](http://www.norwegian.com/) is your best option.

**How I find these rates**

Enter [SkyScanner](http://www.skyscanner.com) and write:

- Set One Way
- From: Any European country (I've tested Spain and Norway)
- To: Just type "US"
- Depart "May 2015" Whole month
- Click on Search

You must repeat this procedure with every European country.

Comment: "repeat this procedure with every European country" -- Try typing "Europe" instead of a specific country.  Adioso is an alternative to SkyScanner, and it allows a range of dates to go from one month into another.

Comment: "Europe" don't show any result in SkyScanner for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I actually never booked a single flight through them.

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com) gives the following prices for single routes:

- [Italy to the US](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Italy/United-States): 259 Euro
- [Spain to the US](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Spain/United-States): 290 Euro
- [London to the US](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/London/United-States): 306 Euro

I didn't enter specific dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a tricky problem.

**XL** has reasonably cheap fares from Paris to NY, one way.

(So, travel in summer 2015, about 500 euros .. compare roughly 2000 euros for any other major airline option.)   Hope it helps.